# Is standard Brownian motion (AKA a Wiener process) weakly or strictly stationary?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, stationarity, brownian-motion

## Question

Let $B(t)$ be a [standard Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Characterisations_of_the_Wiener_process) (AKA a Wiener process).

Is $B(t)$ weakly or strictly stationary, particularly as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Definition)?

## My Thoughts

We know, by definition, that its increments are stationary, which implies it is weakly stationary—that its covariance only depends on the length of the intervals:

$$
Cov(B(t),B(t+h)) = Cov(B(u),B(u+h))
$$
for some $h > 0$, and $0<t<u<\infty$

This makes sense because the Wiener process is the integral of a Gaussian process. However, clearly by inspection of a graph we can see that as $ t $ increases the variance increases, too. Moreover:
$$
var(B(t_i)) = t_i < var(B(t_{i+1}) = t_{i+1}
$$
For $0<t_i<t_{i+1}<\infty$

Comment: Doesn't your computation of  $\operatorname{Var}(B(t))$ immediately answer the question?

Comment: Only half the question. It still remains to be confirmed if a Wiener process is weakly stationary.

Comment: I don't think so: since the variance depends on time, it follows immediately that the process cannot be stationary or weakly second-order stationary.  It is only weakly first-order stationary (because the mean is constantly zero).

Comment: I see what you're saying. Yes, you make sense.

Answer (score 5):

A standard Brownian motion (AKA a Wiener process), $B(t)$ is neither strictly stationary nor weakly stationary.

## Strict stationarity

Strict stationarity requires the distribution not be a function of time $t$. For example, if some stochastic process $X(t)$ were strictly stationary, then for $0<t_i<t_{i+1}<\infty$ all $X(t)$ would be equal in distribution, or
$$
X(t_i) \overset{d}{=} X(t_{i+1})\ \forall\ i
$$
But note that for $B(t)$:
$$
var(B(t_i)) = t_i < var(B(t_{i+1})) = t_{i+1}
$$
so
$$
B(t_i) \overset{d}{\neq} B(t_{i+1})
$$

## Weak stationarity

Weak stationarity requires that the covariance only be a function of the length of the interval, and not the interval's location in time.
$$
Cov(B(t),B(t+h)) = Cov(B(u),B(u+h))
$$
for some $h > 0$, and $0<t<u<\infty$

But for $B(t)$:

\begin{align}
Cov(B(t),B(t+h)) & < Cov(B(u),B(u+h)) \\
min(t,t+h) & < min(u,u+h) \\
t & < u
\end{align}

Therefore B(t) is neither strictly nor weakly stationary. This is not to be confused with [stationary intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process#Stationary_increments), however.